# Physical size in different redshift

Tags: angular-diameter

I have only recently started to study astronomy. I would like to ask if I want to get the angle of Mpc under different redshifts, but the result I calculated seems a bit strange. Did I make a mistake while converting?

```
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
import math 
cosmo = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=70, Om0=0.3)

d_A = cosmo.angular_diameter_distance(z=0.3)
print(d_A) #  Mpc

x = 3.29*u.Mpc

theta = (x/d_A *(180/math.pi) *(1/3600))
theta = theta*u.arcsec

print(theta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, except that you should multiply, not divide, by 3600 (you're converting from degrees to arcsec, not the other way round). You get $5.7\times10^{-5}{''}$, but the correct result is 3600<sup>2</sup> times higher, i.e. $738.6''\!\!\!$.

But why not just let `astropy` do the job:

```
z     = 0.3
x     = 3.29 * u.Mpc
theta = x * cosmo.arcsec_per_kpc_proper(z)

print(theta.to(u.arcsec))
---> <Quantity 738.61092463 arcsec>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: @GHC Welcome to Stack Exchange, and excellent first question! it's totally up to you, but in Stack Exchange "thanks" can also be expressed by up voting (there are arrows displayed next to each question and each answer post). I've up voted your question and this answer (they were both zero). Also, at some point if you feel this has answered your question completely you can click the "accept" check mark. Again, it's 100% your choice.